# Error while building android app built with react-native

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo

this is an error from million of errors I'm facing for a few days ago = solving any error leading to a new one !!!

the error attached to the below image

and here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "taplot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "expo": "^29.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.0",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-icon-badge": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-public-ip": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-toaster": "^1.2.2",
    "react-navigation": "^2.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please also add the steps that you followed to get to this error. Did you detach? Did you link anything? Did you change any java/gradle code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add expokit to your project: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html.

Comment: Yes I detached the project , but now I have to test the application inside Expo = right ? will the native plugins will work inside Expo app ??